# How to concat two different array types that extend/inherit the same type?

Tags: typescript

I have two classes that inherit from the same superclass:

```
class Vehicle {}

class Bus extends Vehicle {}

class Truck extends Vehicle {}
```

Let's have two typed arrays:

```
var buses : Bus[];
var trucks : Truck[];
```

and a function that accepts an array of the superclass type.

```
function checkOil(vehicles : Vehicle[]) {}
```

I can pass in array of busses or array of trucks but I can not merge them and pass them together:

```
function checkOil(buses.concat(trucks));


//error TS2082: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
    Types of property 'pop' of types 'Bus[]' and 'Track[]' are incompatible:
```

How do I merge those arrays?

EDIT: [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Vehicle%20%7B%0A%09bar()%20%3A%20void%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0Aclass%20Bus%20extends%20Vehicle%20%7B%0A%09foo()%20%3A%20void%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0Aclass%20Truck%20extends%20Vehicle%20%7B%0A%09foobar()%20%3A%20void%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20buses%3A%20Bus%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0Abuses.push(%7B%7D)%3B%0Avar%20trucks%3A%20Truck%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0Atrucks.push(%7B%7D)%0A%0Afunction%20checkOil(vehicles%3A%20Vehicle%5B%5D)%20%3A%20Vehicle%5B%5D%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20vehicles%3B%0A%7D%0Avar%20reslt%20%3D%20checkOil(buses.concat(trucks))%3B%0Aconsole.log(reslt)%3B)

Comment: You could copy them both into a sufficiently large array of `Vehicle`s. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Concat to array of Vehicle won't work. Copy via for loop will but that is suboptimal, that's why I seek for better solution here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The casting to `<Vehicle[]>` should work

```
function checkOil(vehicles : Vehicle[]) {}

checkOil((<Vehicle[]>buses).concat(trucks));
```

Typescript will cast the `(busses)` to `Vehicle[]`, and the same will be done with the rest

e.g. this will return (in console) two objects - Vehicles

```
class Vehicle
{
    public Type: string;
}
class Bus extends Vehicle
{
    public A: string;
}
class Truck extends Vehicle
{
    public B: number
}

var buses: Bus[] = [];
buses.push({Type: 'Bus', A : 'A1'});
var trucks: Truck[] = [];
trucks.push({ Type: 'Truck', B: 1 });

function checkOil(vehicles: Vehicle[]) : Vehicle[]
{
    return vehicles;
}
var result = checkOil((<Vehicle[]>buses).concat(trucks));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Well, the above code snippet is working... am I missing some part of your question?

Comment: If you use *actually* empty classes, you'll basically never get errors. Using empty types to experiment with a structural type system is a recipe for bad results.

Comment: it works as long as they have equal signatures (no methods == equal signatures). Try to add 'class Bus extends Vehicle {
    foo() {}
}' and you will get "Type '{}' is missing property 'foo' from type 'Bus'."

Comment: Sorry guys, I did it in a hurry, ... now the example is working properly... but the concept of casting (*assert* in Typescript) is the way...

Comment: Please, take my updated snippet WILL Work ;) sorry for the fast... but not so accurate answer ;) now it works

Comment: Those parentheses made the difference :). Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just type assert the first array to a common type of the two array types:

```
checkOil((<Vehicle[]>buses).concat(trucks));
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you are right. The Assert is the way

Comment: Sorry guys but that works only as far as the classes signatures are empty. Add a method and you get the same error: http://goo.gl/ThDuMk

Comment: Those parentheses made the difference :). Thanks

Comment: if you edit your answer I can give you the upvote you deserve :)

Comment: The answer has the correct parentheses. The link you posted does not. I'm not sure what you want me to edit.